# Pattern mining scored sequences

Tags: data-mining, sequential-pattern-mining

I've generated some data (example below) and I'm not sure how to go about analyzing it.

| N | #0 | #1 | #2 | #3 | #4 | #5 | #6 | #7 | #8 | #9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 65 | C | A | A | A | C | B | B | B | C | C |
| 90 | C | A | A | A | C | B | B | C | B | C |
| 78 | A | C | A | A | C | B | B | C | B | C |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

The data is generated by first computing all 4200 unique permutations of the string *"CCCCAAABBB"* (where each character corresponds to the column with the same index), then running a simulation for each of them; each permutation is then given a score, *N*, which is a positive integer in the range *[59 .. 113]*. They're then sorted by score, ascending; a lower score is better. So, in short, the only relevant information in the data is the ordering of the three *A*'s & *B*'s and four *C*'s, and the score associated with that ordering.

I've put the full dataset [here](https://pastebin.com/yrtdRvFy) in case anyone wants to take a closer look.

After spending some time looking at the data, hoping to find some obvious patterns, I've decided to turn to some more quantitative methods because I wasn't really able to find anything. Ideally, I'd like to be able to have observations like *"most entries with a low score start with some pattern X"*, or *"the top 200 strings contain the pattern X"*, or *"the pattern X is only present in strings with a score higher than Y"*.

I've thought about using some frequent sequence mining methods such as SPADE or PrefixSpan, but I'm not sure whether they would really be appropriate in my case, and I'm not sure how to incorporate the score in these algorithms (as without the score, the patterns are meaningless since the entries are just all the permutations of the same string). The obvious approach here would be to run SPADE (or any other similar algorithm) on say the top/bottom X% strings that were split into itemsets of size 1, and work from there, but maybe there's already some algorithm or process that I'm not aware of that is designed exactly for this type of data.

I'm looking for any potential insight or advice on the best way to proceed; thank you!